# How to calculate CPU % using DIgital Ocean Monitoring API

Tags: linux, server, digital-ocean, cpu-usage

I'm using DigitalOcean for my server. On their dashboard they have some graphs for different monitoring purposes, one of them being CPU %.

[image]

I want to create my own graph for this using their [Monitoring API](https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/api/api-reference/#operation/monitoring_get_DropletCpuMetrics).

Using the "Get Droplet CPU Metrics" endpoint I get the result below, but I don't understand how to calculate the CPU %.

URL:

https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/monitoring/metrics/droplet/cpu?host_id=xxxxxxxxx&start=1663225800&end=1663225800

Result:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "resultType": "matrix",
        "result": [
            {
                "metric": {
                    "host_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
                    "mode": "idle"
                },
                "values": [
                    [
                        1663234200,
                        "974654.94"
                    ]
                ]
            },
            {
                "metric": {
                    "host_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
                    "mode": "iowait"
                },
                "values": [
                    [
                        1663234200,
                        "6101.52"
                    ]
                ]
            },
            {
                "metric": {
                    "host_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
                    "mode": "irq"
                },
                "values": [
                    [
                        1663234200,
                        "0"
                    ]
                ]
            },
            {
                "metric": {
                    "host_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
                    "mode": "nice"
                },
                "values": [
                    [
                        1663234200,
                        "58.76"
                    ]
                ]
            },
            {
                "metric": {
                    "host_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
                    "mode": "softirq"
                },
                "values": [
                    [
                        1663234200,
                        "162.72"
                    ]
                ]
            },
            {
                "metric": {
                    "host_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
                    "mode": "steal"
                },
                "values": [
                    [
                        1663234200,
                        "202.2"
                    ]
                ]
            },
            {
                "metric": {
                    "host_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
                    "mode": "system"
                },
                "values": [
                    [
                        1663234200,
                        "36283.5"
                    ]
                ]
            },
            {
                "metric": {
                    "host_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
                    "mode": "user"
                },
                "values": [
                    [
                        1663234200,
                        "156733.06"
                    ]
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The server has 2 vCPUs, if that is of any use.

I found [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/get-cpu-usage#1-getting-cpu-usage-using-vmstat) from which I tried calculating it myself, but with no luck.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

hey i was doing the same thing and had the same issue, i posted the issue on digitalocean community and i got an answer
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/calculating-cpu-usage-from-the-monitoring-api?comment=196402

> I believe that the crucial part here is to pass the time frame that you want to get the CPU usage for by defining the start and end parameters.
> start: Timestamp to start metric window. Example: start=1620683817
> end: Timestamp to end metric window. Example: end=162070541
> That way you can define which time period you want the CPU usage for, as if you don’t pass this you will get an average for the complete CPU usage.

and the here is the bash script (tested)

```
#!/bin/bash

TOKEN="your_digitalocean_token"
HOST_ID="your_host_id"
API_ENDPOINT="https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/monitoring/metrics/droplet/cpu?host_id=$HOST_ID&start=$(date +%s)&end=$(date +%s)"

# Get the metrics
RESPONSE=$(curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" $API_ENDPOINT)

# Parse the metrics
IDLE=$(echo $RESPONSE | jq -r '[.data.result[] | select(.metric.mode == "idle") | .values[0][1]] | add')
TOTAL=$(echo $RESPONSE | jq -r '[.data.result[] | .values[0][1] | tonumber] | add')

echo "IDLE: $IDLE"
echo "TOTAL: $TOTAL"

USED=$(echo "$TOTAL - $IDLE" | bc)

echo "USED: $USED"

ZERO_CHECK=$(echo "$TOTAL == 0" | bc)
if [ $ZERO_CHECK -eq 1 ]
then
  echo "No change in TOTAL, can't calculate CPU Usage"
else
  CPU_USAGE=$(echo "scale=2; ($USED / $TOTAL) * 100" | bc)
  echo "CPU Usage: $CPU_USAGE%"
fi
```

hope it helps

Comment: hatem ben tayeb, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @mozway EDIT: ah, I see they've embedded the real script now..